# Should I edit `.config` file manually to disable `AUDITSYSCALL` in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, configuration-files

Some Real Time systems (e.g. RTAI, Xenomai) suggest deactivating the `AUDITSYSCALL` option, while I cannot find such option to disable it after execute the command `sudo make menuconfig`.

I search the `AUDITSYSCALL`, finding it doesn't corresponds with an option in `menuconfig` and its description only says `defined in init/Kconfig`, so I cannot configure it in the `menuconfig`.

So, my question is should I manually edit the kernel configuration to disable `AUDITSYSCALL`? (e.g. CONF_AUDITSYSCALL=n)

P.S. My kernel version is 4.14.111 .

---

**UPDATE**

I found a solution from somewhere, and solved my problem, meeting no error or bug so far. I don't know if it is a correct answer, so I just post it below.

In kernel source directory,

`sudo vim init/Kconfig`

find the following configuation,

`config AUDITSYSCALL
    def_bool y
    depends on AUDIT && HAVE_ARCH_AUDITSYSCALL`

replace it with

`config AUDITSYSCALL
    bool "Enable system-call auditing support"
    depends on AUDIT && HAVE_ARCH_AUDITSYSCALL
    default y if SECURITY_SELINUX
    help
      Enable low-overhead system-call auditing infrastructure that
      can be used independently or with another kernel subsystem,
      such as SELinux.`

Then, you could find configurable option(`Enable system-call auditing support`) for `ADUITSYSCALL` under the `General Setup`.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I edit `.config` file manually to disable `AUDITSYSCALL` in linux kernel?

No, you should not manually edit the **.config** file.

> I search the `AUDITSYSCALL`, finding it doesn't corresponds with an option in `menuconfig` and its description only says `defined in init/Kconfig`, so I cannot configure it in the `menuconfig`.

How did you perform this "search"?
Did you use the search capability of `make menuconfig`?

The `AUDITSYSCALL` symbol is declared in **init/Kconfig** as

```
config AUDITSYSCALL
    def_bool y
    depends on AUDIT && HAVE_ARCH_AUDITSYSCALL
```

Since the dependency `AUDIT` is declared as

```
config AUDIT
    bool "Auditing support"
    depends on NET
    help
      Enable auditing infrastructure that can be used with another
      kernel subsystem, such as SELinux (which requires this for
      logging of avc messages output).  System call auditing is included
      on architectures which support it.
```

disabling this "Auditing support" option should effectively disable  `AUDITSYSCALL`.

BTW you should not have to use sudo in order to make the kernel.  Something is setup incorrectly in the user or build environment if superuser privileges seems necessary.

Comment: I search `AUDITSYSCALL` under `menuconfig` as you mentioned. `AUDITSYSCALL` depends on `AUDIT` which further depends on `NET`, but it is unreasonable to deactivate `NET` since it will disable the network connection.

Comment: I updated my question, further discussions are welcome ^_^

Comment: *"but it is unreasonable to deactivate `NET`..."* -- I made no mention regarding `NET`.   I suggested simply disabling the "Auditing support" option, which is not going to affect whatever the `NET` setting is.  Are you confusing `depends on ...` with `selects ...`?